# Approximating max degree $3$ perfect matching count?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, permanent

We do not have a deterministic constant factor approximation scheme for general $n\times n$ $0/1$ permanent.

What is the best factor in deterministic approximation schemes if we only care counting bipartite perfect matching with average degree in $[2,3]$ and max degree $3$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is known about counting bipartite perfect matching with average degree in $[2,3]$ and max degree $3$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38685/what-is-known-about-counting-bipartite-perfect-matching-with-average-degree-in)

Comment: @MikhailRudoy not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dagum and Luby](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397592902347) show (using a construction credited to [Dahlhaus and Karpinski](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000092900054)) how to construct, given a bipartite graph $G$, a bipartite graph $G'$ of maximum degree $3$ such that $G'$ has exactly as many perfect matchings as $G$ (see Theorem 6.2.). Then from $G'$ you can construct a graph $G''$ with average degree arbitrarily close to $2$ and twice as many perfect matchings as $G'$, as I explained [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38685/what-is-known-about-counting-bipartite-perfect-matching-with-average-degree-in). Both constructions are in polynomial time. Therefore, the best polytime deterministic approximation to the number of perfect matchings of a graph of maximum degree 3, and average degree in $[2,3]$ is equal to the best polytime deterministic approximation to the permanent of a 0-1 matrix. As far as I know, this is the factor $2^n$ approximation achieved by [Gurvits and Samorodnitsky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0976).

(It may be helpful to note that a $\exp(n^\varepsilon)$ approximation for $\varepsilon < 1$ would imply an FPTAS.)

Comment: do you know which page they talk about this construction in Dagum and Luby and also how many vertices are used in $G'$?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's Theorem 6.2. The proof is on page 299. $G'$ has $2m - n/2$ vertices, where $m$ is the number of edges of $G$ and $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$.